# "beyond bounds [0 .. 1]" message on StackScrollView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, ios5

I'm trying to implement StackScrollView (https://github.com/Reefaq/StackScrollView) into my project, but, instead of a stack of tableviews, I want a stack of views loaded from a nib.
I created a button and added it to the rootViewController.m;

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    rootView = [[UIViewExt alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    rootView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth + UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    [rootView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.6]];

    UIButton *buttonBar;

    buttonBar = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [buttonBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonBar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gray.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
    buttonBar.frame = CGRectMake(9, 40, [UIImage imageNamed:@"www_gray.png"].size.width, [UIImage imageNamed:@"www_gray.png"].size.width);
    [buttonBar addTarget:self action:@selector(newPage) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [rootView addSubview:buttonBar];
}
```

here's the method the buttonBar calls:

```
 -(void)newPage{
    UIDetailController *paginaGenerica = [[UIDetailController alloc] initWithNibName:@"UIDetailController" bundle:nil];
    [[StackScrollViewAppDelegate instance].rootViewController.stackScrollViewController addViewInSlider:paginaGenerica invokeByController:self isStackStartView:FALSE];
}
```

When I touch the button for the first time, everything works fine. But, when I touch it again, I receive this:

```
 2012-01-23 10:53:46.263 StackScrollView[1048:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 2147483648 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'
 *** First throw call stack:
```

In fact, I receive this same message when I try to animate rootView (make the entire content move to the right, and come back later, when I swipe over a specific view) more than 1 time too.

But, I add the same button and method to the UIDetailController.m (make the own View add new Views on top of itself, just like the tableViews work on the original implementation of StackScrollView), then, everything works perfectly.

I think the problem is inside "StackScrollViewController.m", but, I'm kind of new to programming, so, I didn't understand same parts of the code. If, someone has already worked with StackViewController and has faced this situation could help...

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on button for the first time make the following change

```
[[StackScrollViewAppDelegate instance].rootViewController.stackScrollViewController addViewInSlider:paginaGenerica invokeByController:self isStackStartView:**TRUE**];
```

and for every successive click on paginaGenerica view

```
[[StackScrollViewAppDelegate instance].rootViewController.stackScrollViewController addViewInSlider:paginaGenerica invokeByController:self isStackStartView:FALSE];
```